# How many px occupy the single &nbsp;?

Tags: html, css

I just want to know the how many "px" occupy the single "&nbsp". so that i can calculate and give the padding instead of &nbsp

Comment: You want to know in general? `&nbsp;` is just a non-breaking space, its size is going to differ from font to font and change along with font size.

Comment: can you please tell me how many px occupy while using font-size:12px;

Comment: @MRTK: like John said - it depends on which font you're using. a 12px nbsp in Arial is going to be different from a 12px nbsp in Helvetica is going to be different from a 12px nbsp in Impact etc...

Comment: not sure about that, I think characters using the same style can have different 'sizes' depending on kerning. for ex: the size of "AV" can be shorter that the sum of the size of "A" and "V". I don't know if it applies on spaces. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not possible to know this accurately, because it will depend on the font's metrics and the way it's rendered.  A non-breaking space is usually rendered with the same width as a regular space in the same font, it just suggests to the browser not to wrap at that point or collapse the space.

You should never rely on fonts rendering a particular way in order to line up design elements on the page.  Specify distances in units that are appropriate, and don't use non-breaking spaces in situations for which they aren't suitable.

You could start with a value of, say, around `0.4em`.  But if you absolutely have to exactly match the width of a non-breaking space, you are using a non-breaking space incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the font and its size. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hUFh4/

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the font and font size you are using: http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/CV5mQ/

Answer (score 0):

Today (2022) you can use the CSS `ch` unit - which is supposed to represent the width of one "character" of the current font. Some implementations have `1 ch` be equal to the width of the space character, some of them have it to be equal to the width of the `0` character.

This is generally, roughly equal to ~60% of the font-size - but it can be completely different on certain (non monospace) fonts.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the font size. Even you can calculate it on Photoshop.
In html:

```
<p>How are you? &nbps; what are you doing?</p>
```

copy this from browser and paste it in photoshop:
it will look like this:
How are you?   what are you doing?
Then zoom it and check the px.
If you want.