# Width in pixel of &nbsp; in span and iframe body

Tags: html, css

I need to know the width of a `&nbsp;` in pixels, and whether it depends on the font-size. Also, does this vary across different elements in the page?

Also, is the `&nbsp;` different from a regular ?

Comment: There is no width in pixels. It depends on the font and font size being rendered (which can be changed by the user, you know).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many px occupy the single &nbsp;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925339/how-many-px-occupy-the-single-nbsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Maccath's answer is the correct advice to follow, to answer your question directly: Yes, you can actually [get the width quite simply](http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/hUFh4/29/) by using some javascript:

For instance, given:

```
<span id="nbsp">&nbsp;</span>
```

The width can be retrieved using jQuery:

```
$('#nbsp').width()
```

jQuery returns the width of the `<span>` as it is rendered, so it accounts for font-size, etc. Now that you know how to do it, don't.

Comment: I don't see any problems in your example. Note that the `&nbsp;` doesn't stretch, it's only the spaces before it that stretches. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/HNxnY/5/ I put a border around all the spans to visualize the actual size each `&nbsp;`, and they appear consistent with the reported values. The last span contains only a normal space (and no surrounding spaces to avoid collapsing), and is therefore stretched, which is also reflected in the last reported value.

Comment: on my desktop, the three values are different (51,99 and 78 for the normal space). I hardly see how this can be considered reliable. My point here is that there's no reliable method to tell the size of a space in web pages. Justification was a way to demonstrate it, but i'm almost sure they're other means (kerning for example).

Comment: I looked at it in Chrome now, which scales the nbsp differently than Opera when using `justify`, and indeed, I get different values. But they still appear to be correct compared to how the spaces are rendered (as visualized by the borders). So I still don't see anything that's incorrect. Whether kerning affects the values remains to be seen, but even if it does then the correctness or reliability depends on your definition of character width in the presence of kerning...

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) over a normal space is to prevent a line break between the words. You can use multiple `&nbsp;` entities to have multiple spaces together. If you just add a space without using the `&nbsp;` entity, they will be reduced to just a single space.

If you are using multiple `&nbsp;`s to pad out content, as some beginner HTML users do, then this is considered incorrect. You should always pad content using CSS margins and paddings to maintain semantic correctness, and separate style from page content.

The width of the `&nbsp;` depends on the font size, letter spacing, etc. same as with any other character, and as stated, this can be changed by the user, so there is no reliable way of knowing.

Comment: True, but the actual point of nbsp (non-breaking space) is that it doesn't let a line be split (e.g. "20&nbsp;000" would make sure there's no line break between the numbers). Preventing whitespace collapse is just a side effect.

Comment: Can it be safely assumed that it will be less that equal to the font size ??? Also do all the elements on a page give the same width to it if their font-family and size are same ????

Comment: In actual i am posting the same content inside an iframe body and a span and the width of the iframe is determined using the scrollWidth of the span.All works fine till I add a space from the keyboard.

Comment: You can assume that it will be <= the font size, but I don't think it's a sure thing. If the font size, font, and letter spacing, and all other styling is the same then yes, the `&nbsp`s should be of equal size in different elements... but the trick is making sure that all that stuff is the same. If the iframe is inside the span, you could try setting the iframe's width using a percentage, which would be relative to the span.